# Foundation 4 framework with plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

Can we include plain Javascript code with Foundation 4 zurb framework? That is I dont want to use the provided Zepto or the jQuery plugins.I want to include some plain JavaScript code without using any Javascript frameworks like Zepto or jQuery. Is it possible?

Comment: You can include vanilla javascript in any project delivered to the browser (assuming javascript isn't disabled).  Just create a new script file and include it in the head of the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zurb Foundation calls its javascript as methods of the `Foundation` object.  So unless you're trying to include a new script that uses that object there's no reason why you can't include your own scripts in the same document.

To do this, simply add your script to the document as you would if Zurb Foundation wasn't included in the project.  Be careful with jQuery though, as Foundation comes packaged with its own version, and including more than one instance/version of jQuery can lead to problems.

I won't go into detail about where/when/why to include scripts, but the easiest example of doing so would be:

```
<head>
    <script src="your/scripts/dir/script.js"></script>
</head>
```

Also, as a side note, make sure you have a good reason for including a framework as big as Foundation.  It has a large footprint which isn't generally worth the performance cost if you're not using a large segment of its core functionality.